# org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Employee_detail is not mapped [from Employee_detail]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, servlets

my sql query is `select * from employee_detail;`

error is:-

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/Roster_APP] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Employee_detail is not mapped [from Employee_detail]] with root cause
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Employee_detail is not mapped [from Employee_detail]
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:158)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:87)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:70)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3056)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2945)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:688)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:281)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:229)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:228)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:160)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1623)
at com.lak.dao.impl.EmployeeDaoImpl.getAllEmployee(EmployeeDaoImpl.java:45)
at com.lak.service.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl.getAllEmployee(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.getAllEmployee(Unknown Source)
at com.lak.controller.EmployeeContoller.getAllEmployee(EmployeeContoller.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

controller is:

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeContoller {
@Autowired
private EmployeeServices employeeServices;

@RequestMapping("/index")
public String setupForm(Map<String,Object>map){

    Employee employee=new Employee();
    map.put("employee", employee);
    map.put("employee_List", employeeServices.getAllEmployee());
    return "employee";

}



@RequestMapping(value = "/employeeList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public  @ResponseBody ArrayList<Employee> getAllEmployee() {



    System.out.println("-------------- inside getUsers() ...");

    ArrayList<Employee> employee_List = (ArrayList<Employee>) employeeServices.getAllEmployee();

    return employee_List;

}



}
```

dao file is:

```
public interface EmployeeDao {
public void add(Employee employee);
public void edit(Employee employee);
public void delete(String empNumer);
public Employee getEmployee(String empNumer);
public List getAllEmployee();

}
```

daoimpl.java is

```
@Repository

public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory session;

    @Override
    public void add(Employee employee) {

        session.getCurrentSession().save(employee);

    }

    @Override
    public void edit(Employee employee) {
        session.getCurrentSession().update(employee);

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(String empNumer) {
        session.getCurrentSession().delete(getEmployee(empNumer));

    }

    @Override
    public Employee getEmployee(String empNumer) {
        return (Employee)session.getCurrentSession().get(Employee.class, empNumer);
    }

    @Override
    public List getAllEmployee() {
        return session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from employee_detail").list();
    }


}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>     

     <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <!-- Assume hibernateTutorial is the database name -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/roster_app</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class"> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext
</property>
        <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3600</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">28800</property>   
        <mapping class="com.lak.model.Employee" />

    </session-factory>         
</hibernate-configuration>
```

how to i solve this problem?

Comment: You aren't writing SQL you are writing HQL... Although similar quite different languages. You want `from Employee` instead.

Comment: how i change `getAllEmployee` method?

Comment: Change to what? You are using entities and an ORM then use it. If you start creating SQL then why use an ORM tool anyway? Open the method in an IDE and change the query to what I mentioned.

Comment: i did't clear you mention!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M. Deinum's comment is correct. You need to be using HQL. Without seeing your ORM model but judging by your hibernate.cfg.xml you have an ORM class named Employee which leads me to believe Employee_detail is a column inside the Employee table in your database. Is this correct? if so what you want is an HQL query similar to:

`SELECT employee_detail FROM Employee`

which will provide you with the results of the employee_detail column.
if you simply want a list of Employee objects then you want your query to just be:

`FROM Employee`

that will provide you with a list of Employee objects, each with their own fields for whatever columns you have in your database table. Take a look at this method:

```
@Override
public List getAllEmployee() {
    return session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Employee").list();
}
```